# Mechwarrior (esp. Mercenaries / Vengeance) with Joystick / HOTAS on Win7x64?

Tags: controllers, backwards-compatibility, mechwarrior-4-mercenaries

I've spent all day yesterday getting Mechwarrior 4: Mercenaries to work on my machine, and, behold! It finally works and runs. But all I can do is stare at the inside of my Mechs' cockpit, as I had to use the gosnoJoystick (and gosnoVideo) command line arguments to even get it to run. Playing with anything but my trusty HOTAS is no fun. =/

Are there any tricks or hacks for getting MW4Mercs.exe to run, without having to use /gosnojoystick, or some way to use my controllers even when running it with /gosnojoystick? I've got Xpadder and a few other things here... all I could think of at this point would be to somehow ghetto this and map my mouse to the stick, and create zones along my throttle to trigger key presses... absolutely no fun...

I've not yet tried to install Vengeance again, so IDK if that one behaves better than Mercs... any ideas...?

Comment: My Logitech 3d pro works in W10. It has a throttle and a crappy third axis, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Many old games will still recognize USB joysticks/controllers in Windows 7 and Windows 10. The only time I've run into an issue is with Earthsiege 2, which is so old it looks for a joystick connected via 15-pin game port. For ES2, I had to use the Microsoft Application Compatibility Toolkit to create a custom compatibility profile for ES2. This was years ago, but if I recall correctly it took about an hour of research and playing around to figure out how to get it to recognize a USB joystick.

(I would happily share my ES2 configuration to get you started, but I have upgraded my system to Windows 10 and can't seem to open the old ACT to view the old configuration.)